# How to overwrite a label in tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, inheritance

Edited to *try* and make it clearer, but basically this code below doesn't overwrite the text of the label, but it overwrites the title of the window. How would I make it so that the `self.label` gets updated in the same way the `master.title` gets updated?

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Title")

        self.label = Label(master, text="Label")

class login(GUI):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        master.title("New Title")

        self.label = Label(master, text="New Label")
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `self.label.config(text="New label")` to update your label content, to change your master title, you only have to use `self.master.title("New Title")`

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Title")
        self.label = Label(master, text="Label")

class login(GUI):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        master.title("New Title")
        self.label.config(text="New Label")
```

Comment: There is no point to the `self.master = master` inside the `login` class.